# Would I lose any benefits if I switch from Vuex to custom Javascript store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am making a game editor. All it needs is a way to save and read data from a common store, such as sprites and tool settings.

The problem is Vuex just seems really messy to me. Maybe it's because I'm not building a standard SPA which Vuex was designed for, but it just seems that every time I want to do something simple it adds 50+ lines of code in getters, actions, and mutations that would otherwise be unnecessary. On top of that, it has limitations such as not being able to modify states from getters which would be really helpful when generating unique asset IDs. I also have no need for the dynamic loading/unloading of modules.

So my question, if I replaced Vuex with an imported object like the following:

```
class MyStore_Class{
    constructor(){
        this.val = 0;
    }

    //other methods and stuff to manipulate data
}

let MyStore = new MyStore();

export default MyStore;
```

Then imported this `MyStore` object into the components where I needed it, would I lose anything?

I ran some simple tests and it seems like it works perfectly as a drop in replacement for Vuex, but I'm afraid there might be some kind of downside that I would notice only later down the line.

EXIT: Pretty much all data for the app is local, so the separation of actions/mutations tends to mean that the only action code I am writing is `commit('doMutation', newData)` over and over again

Comment: Don't you need a reactivity?

Comment: I don't know your full use case but if it's a really simple app then Vuex _may_ be overkill and perhaps you should just consider using props, but I would never get rid of Vuex for a homegrown state management, you're just asking for trouble there

Comment: My use case is storing lists of objects (sprites, game objects, rooms), being able to retrieve them from any component, as well as being able to store and retrieve currently selected asset, tools, etc. I use interface tabs, so these states also need to be saved and loaded when a component is destroyed and created respectively. Using the custom store seemed to be reactive when I used computed properties to get the object value, but like I said it was just a simple test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution could be a vue observable, really easy to do and lightweight in term of architecture ;)

1. Create a store.js file in your src/root folder
2. Create the state value/s you wish to have globally
3. Create the methods you needs for his interaction
4. Set it up in your components and there you go

Setup store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
const state = Vue.observable({ val: 0 });
export const increment = () => state.counter++;
export const decrement = () => state.counter--;
export default state;
```

In your component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>The value is {{val}}</p>
    <button @click="inc">+</button>
    <button @click="dec">-</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import store, { increment, decrement } from "./store";
  export default {
    computed: {
// your getter in some way
      counter() {
        return store.counter;
      }
    }, 
    methods: {
      inc() {
        increment();
      },
      dec() {
        decrement();
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

I took these examples on this article, where you could read more  about vue observable if you want, but i use it a lot on small projects where i need just few values accessible globally and that doesn't require a vuex architecture.

https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-manage-vues-state-with-vue-observable-25988a88938b

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I'm looking for. Even though my backend can get a little complex, a lot of the things I need to use Vuex for just turn out way more messy than they should. This should fix that problem